# How can I make a notepad in java?

Tags: java

I need to make a notepad++ software in java as my project.how i can make this?I want to do everything step by step.

Answer (score 3):

[Tutorial](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/66176-creating-a-basic-notepad-application/) for you.

Answer (score 2):

Learn about [Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/). Then learn about [Character Encodings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html). Ask questions here if you need specific help.

Answer (score 1):

You may find the tutorial [*Using Text Components*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started: [Editor based on JTextPane](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/EditorbasedonJTextPane.htm)

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about **the** [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) beware it is a very rich editor. It is in version 5.9 now and has been around for many years. Be prepared for hard work in order to achieve its functionality.

If you want to write a text editor with the basic functionality like the notepad.exe, this you can do in 2 hours with Swing.